# How to get access to OneDrive through webDAV on Android?

Tags: android, webdav, onedrive, sardine

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
1, what's OneDrive WebDAV address?
2, the [Sardine-Android](https://github.com/aflx/Sardine-Android) library is the best choice for this? Is there other great libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sardine is definitely the best choice for this at the time of asking. In my limited experience with mapping OneDrive to WebDAV ...  The URL is "https://d.docs.live.net/" followed by your CustomerID. For example: "https://d.docs.live.net/3326236354f636b7333g3/"

Comment: If you have concerns with Sardine, rolling your own WebDAV client is a pretty easy thing to do, since it is essentially HTTP extensions.